# iOS: Stream audio/video from smb

Tags: ios, audio, video, stream, smb

Is there any possibilities to stream audio/video content from smb shares in iOS application?

Are AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController support this?

[Updated from comments]

> using MPMoviePlayerController you can do this

So, how can I authorize MPMoviePlayerController?

I can read data from SMB shares, so I can download file to local storage and play. But if file is too big it may take too much time.

For example: FileBrowser application can stream video and audio from smb.

Comment: using MPMoviePlayerController you can do this,

Comment: What url format do I have to use? "smb://192.168.100.1/movie.mp4" - is it right?

Comment: And what about authorization?

Comment: smb://192.168.100.1/-video.MOV try like this or any format

Comment: i am not sure about authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use MPMoviePlayerController for stream from SMB.

A solution that I used is a webserver in the app that make as proxy for the SMB client and `MPMoviePlayerController`.